# Gimp - jagged pencil and brush strokes [SOLVED]

Tags: gimp, stroke, drawing, brush, drawing-tablet

I am using Gimp 2.8.14 on Ubuntu 14.04 and a Wacom tablet (Intuos 3 6x8).

My problem is that I cannot make a smooth stroke even when I check the Smooth stroke in the Tool Options panel. When I do that the problem is less evident, but is still there.

I believe the tablet is not the problem because in Krita the problem does not appear.

[image: Exemple of me trying to write my own name with the pencil tool and a stroke with the brush tool:]

Here is the link if you cannot see it:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7mcZJoyvCM0SHVIeFVuWEJiU2M/view?pli=1

I have already uninstalled Gimp and installed it again and the problem persists.

Can you please give some directions to solve the problem?

Thank you, very much.

Comment: Did you try with different setting for *Smooth stroke* quality and weight?

Comment: This looks like your stroke is snapping to the grid. Can you make sure that this isn't turned on?

Comment: @Takkat, yes I tried different values after checking the Smooth parameter and I had to put both at the maximum values to have the desired results.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher, your answer solved the problem. The **View > Snap to Grid** option was turned on. As soon as I turned it off, the problem was fixed. Thank you very much. If you want, you can create an answer to this question and I can mark it as solved. I believe it counts points for you and your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Schumacher (@MichaelSchumacher) pointed out in his comment, the

**View > Snap to Grid**

option was turned on and, as a result, interfering with the brush strokes.

Just turn it off and everything is OK.

**Do not check the "Smooth stroke" paramenter** at the **Tool Options panel,** because it will slow down your machine a lot. I tried that and, to have the desired result, I put the values at the maximum levels. I could not paint freely after that.